# Is there a simple way to merge values based on keys in Swift dictionaries?

Tags: swift, dictionary, concatenation, higher-order-functions

I have a text divided into an array of strings where the user can tap on each word, adding the word's index (key) and the string (value) to a dictionary.

Now, if the user adds two or more words that are adjacent, I would like the concatenate the string and make them share one index.

My idea was to use a computed property that rearranges the array of strings based on the keys and values in the dictionary. So when the user taps on a word, the function should  update the dictionary while checking if there are any adjacent indexes already added.

Example code:

```
let text = "This is a test for merging adjacent words that the user has selected."

//The text divided in separate words that can be tapped
var arrayOfString: [String] {
    text.components(separatedBy: " ")
}

//If a user taps on a word it will be saved with its index
var userSelectedWords: [Int:String] = [2 : "a", 3 : "test", 4 : "for", 6 : "adjacent", 7 : "words", 9 : "the", 11 : "has"]

//Mapping all the keys into an array
var selectedKeys = userSelectedWords.map { $0.key }.sorted()
var indexToRemove = [Int]()

for i in 0..<selectedKeys - 1 {
//If the key has a value of one less that the succeding key, the words are adjacent
    if selectedKeys[i] == selectedKeys[i + 1] - 1 {
        indexToRemove.append(selectedKeys[i+1])
        if let currentWord = userSelectedWords[selectedKeys[i]], let nextWord = userSelectedWords[selectedKeys[i + 1]] {
            concatenatedString.append("\(currentWord) \(nextWord)")
        }
    }
}

print(indexToRemove)
//Prints: [3, 4, 7] which are the indexes that should be removed.


print(concatenatedString)
//Prints: ["a test", "test for", "adjacent words"]

/*
 Here I'm stuck. If there are more than two words adjacent, the function will of
 course continue the iteration and create a new item in the concatenatedString.
 It feels like it starts to get way too complicated.
 */
```

I'd very much appreciate any input or help in this regard. Maybe I'm just looking at it the wrong way...

Comment: Hey Soundtwig, welcome to the sight. This looks like a pretty well-formulated question. You tried something, showed us the code, but I think you're missing one key piece: what result are you hoping to get at the end?

Comment: On second thought, I'm having trouble understanding your problem. The English description of your problem at the top of your question is more-or-less just an English rendition of what the Swift code does. I can read the Swift code :) Can you go into more detail about your problem, an example input, the expected output, and a deeper explanation as to *what*you're trying to achieve  (not *how* you're trying to achieve it) ?

Comment: Hi and thank you for the quick answers. I guess I should have elaborated more on the results that I need. The user will be able to select certain words and add those to a custom database. When a new text is entered, any words that match a word in the database will be highlighted. The user can choose to add new words to the database. Since I don't want to limit it so single words, but also expressions, the function should concatenate any words that are adjacent. I ran a quick test of Joakim Danielsons answer, and it seems to give me what I need. I run some more tests and get back.

Comment: Sorry for the late update. The reason I decided to change my approach was the fact that the selected indexes needed to be updated with an offset, every time the user merged any words preceeding already selected words. The merging would of course decrease the number of indexes in the array. Both Joakim and Rob's answer helped me to solve my initial problem though. For me the functional approach is easier to read, but I would not mind keeping Joakims suggestion as an answer to the question, since it is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

A functional approach would be to create an array of `Range` objects based upon the contiguous sorted keys, and then filter for those whose length was greater than 1

```swift
let text = "This is a test for merging adjacent words that the user has selected."
let allWords = text.components(separatedBy: " ")
let userSelectedWords = [2 : "a", 3 : "test", 4 : "for", 6 : "adjacent", 7 : "words", 9 : "the", 11 : "has"]

let result = userSelectedWords.keys
    .sorted()
    .reduce(into: [Range]()) { ranges, index in
        if let range = ranges.last, range.endIndex == index {
            ranges[ranges.count - 1] = range.startIndex ..< index + 1
        } else {
            ranges.append(index ..< index + 1)
        }
    }
    .filter { $0.count > 1 }
    .map { allWords[$0].joined(separator: " ") }

print(result) // ["a test for", "adjacent words"]
```